# Books on Mac won't download epubs from iCloud

Tags: mac, icloud, books

I use Books on Mac (Big Sur) to organize my non-Apple epub library. Books successfully syncs across devices, and when I want to read a book on my Mac, I often need to click the cloud download button in the top right corner of the book cover to download the book.

At some point recently, downloading stopped working on Mac (only). When I click the button, the title is added to the 'download manager' ("Show Downloads" next to the "All Books" link), however the progress indicator spins endlessly and the books are not downloaded.

I have 15GB free on my 512GB disk, running Big Sur 11.2.3 on a Macbook Pro 2017.

Any idea why this might be happening and what I can do about it?

[image: Apple books not downloading]

Answer (score 0):

Updating Mac OS fixed the issue for me. I'm a little confused because I thought I was on 11.2.3 and after update I'm still on 11.2.3, but alas—it now works.

Comment: Some months later, still on 11.2.3, the problem has reappeared